# Extract value from JSON array for use in where clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table which contains two columns; **Player** (VARCHAR), and **Availability** (JSON/VARCHAR). The data in this table is similar to the below:

```
Player         Availability
-------+-------------------------------
John   | { "Availability": [1, 3, 6] }
Yusuf  | { "Availability": [3, 4, 7] }
Ben    | { "Availability": [1, 2, 3] }
```

What I'm wanting is to write a query which will show me what players are available on a certain day (the numbers in the Availability column represent days).

Something like:

```
SELECT Player 
FROM TableName 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(Availability, '$.Availability') = 3;
```

This would return: John, Yusuf, and Ben.

Is this achievable?

Comment: ok, have you tried it?

Comment: I've tried so many options. Closest I got was the query returning the Availability as an array. But obviously, this wouldn't allow me to compare values.

Comment: Another great reason to use properly normalized data in a relational database instead of data stored in a data interchange format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `OPENJSON`:

```
SELECT t.player, json.value
FROM TableName t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Availability,'$.Availability') json
WHERE json.value = 3
```

Comment: Getting the error "invalid object name OPENJSON", despite my database compatibility level being at 130. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, my query window was set the wrong server. Thank you for your help!